# How Can I vectorize this function to return an index vector?

Tags: r

I'm new to R and am trying to get a handle on the apply family of functions.  Specifically, I am trying to write a higher-order function that will accept 2 character vectors, "host", and "guest" (which do not need to be the same length) and return me an index vector the same length as "host", with the resulting elements corresponding to their indices in guest (NA if not there).

```
host <- c("A","B","C","D")
guest <- c("D","C","A","F")

matchIndices <- function(x,y)
{
  return(match(x,y))
}
```

This code returns 3 as expected:

```
matchIndices(host[1],guest)
```

This is the loop I'd like to be able to replace with a succinct apply function (sapply?)

```
for (i in 1:length(host)) 
{ idx <- matchIndices(host[i],guest); 
  cat(paste(idx,host[i],"\n",sep=";"))
}
```

This code "works" in that it produces the output below, but I really want the result to be a vector, and I have a hunch that one of the apply functions will do the trick.  I'm just stuck on how to write it.  Any help would be most appreciated.  Thanks.

3;A;
NA;B;
2;C;
1;D;

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
host <- c("A","B","C","D")
guest <- c("D","C","A","F")

matchIndices <- function(x,y) {
    return(match(x,y))
}
```

One (inefficient) way is to `sapply` over the `host` vector, passing in `guest` as an argument (note you could just simplify this to `sapply(host, match, guest)` but this illustrates a general way of approaching this sort of thing):

```
> sapply(host, matchIndices, guest)
 A  B  C  D 
 3 NA  2  1
```

However, this can be done *directly* using `match` as it accepts a vector first argument:

```
> match(host, guest)
[1]  3 NA  2  1
```

If you want a named vector as output,

```
> matched <- match(host, guest)
> names(matched) <- host
> matched
 A  B  C  D 
 3 NA  2  1
```

which could be wrapped into a function

```
matchIndices2 <- function(x, y) {
    matched <- match(x, y)
    names(matched) <- x
    return(matched)
}
```

returning

```
> matchIndices2(host, guest)
 A  B  C  D 
 3 NA  2  1
```

If you *really* want the names and the matches stuck together into a vector of strings, then:

```
> paste(match(host, guest), host, sep = ";")
[1] "3;A"  "NA;B" "2;C"  "1;D"
```

Comment: you could just do `sapply(host, match, guest)`, no need to define `matchIndices`

Comment: @Prasad Yes, you could but I left this like it was to show how to sapply a user function in this fashion. Reason I left it like that was this can all be done with `match` directly as it accepts a vector first argument. See my updated answer.

Comment: This is fabulous.  Thank you very much.  "match(host, guest)" is perfect.  I didn't realize it could be that compact.

Answer (score 3):

if you want the output vector in the `host;guestNum` format you would use `do.call`, `paste`, `match` as follows:

```
> do.call(paste, list(host, sapply(host, match, guest), sep = ';'))                                                                                     
[1] "A;3"  "B;NA" "C;2"  "D;1"
```

Comment: As I said, you don't need `sapply` at all here; `match` takes a vector first argument, so we can simplify this to `do.call(paste, list(host, match(host, guest), sep = ';'))` but that seems like a bit of overkill to achieve `paste(match(host, guest), host, sep = ";")` or `paste(host, match(host, guest), sep = ";")` does it not?

Comment: very true @Gavin, that's the simplest way

Comment: darn, you're right. So `do.call(paste,list(host,match(host,guest),sep=";"))` would do

Comment: @Joris yes if you like reading convoluted R code ;-) It is simpler to call `paste` directly: `paste(host, match(host, guest), sep = ";")`

Answer (score 2):

```
sapply(host , function(x) which(guest==x))
$A
[1] 3

$B
integer(0)

$C
[1] 2

$D
[1] 1


unlist(sapply(host , function(x) which(guest==x)))

    A C D 
    3 2 1 

paste(host, sapply(host , function(x) which(guest==x)), sep=":", collapse=" ")
[1] "A:3 B:integer(0) C:2 D:1"
```